# Shift a Column by one column from a row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to shift the column1 form index 2 1 step down with pandas
i want to make my data from **_from** to **_to**

```
_from =
   Column1  Column2  Column3
0     1     20.0       19
1     2     21.0       23
2     3     33.0       34
3     4     42.0       35

_to =

   Column1  Column2  Column3
0     1     20.0       19
1     2     21.0       23
2     Nan   33.0       34
3     3     42.0       35
```

I tried `df.Column1 = df.Column1.shift(+1)` but it shifts from the top like this:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3
0     Nan     20.0       19
1     1       21.0       23
2     2       33.0       34
3     3       42.0       35
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.iloc` and assign your new column.

```
df.iloc[2:, 0] = df.iloc[2:, 0].shift(1)


   Column1  Column2  Column3
0      1.0     20.0       19
1      2.0     21.0       23
2      NaN     33.0       34
3      3.0     42.0       35
```

Comment: Good solution, I like it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.Column1[2:] = df.Column1[2:].shift(+1)
```

out:

```
  Column1  Column2  Column3
0      1.0     20.0       19
1      2.0     21.0       23
2      NaN     33.0       34
3      3.0     42.0       35
```